# Indexing 20M of records with python and mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I would like to mention about my little project, and if I'm on track. I need work with all articles from Medline (http://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/licensee/2011_stats/baseline_doc.html). For those are not familiar with Medline database, I add a little information:

- There are approx. 20.000.000 of records (83.4 GB disk space), each has many fields and subfields.
- You can download this DB (with license) in XML format.
- These 20M of records are distributed in 653 files.
- Every file has one MedlineCitationSet, and this a set of records (MedlineCitation's).

I want to process these records and get information such as title, abstract... Then I have thought to index these files (or records) with python and mongodb. And I have one option:

I have created a medline parser and for each record is created a JSON entry for mongoDB, and after indexing by pubmedID. Then I can create a function likes get_abstract('pubmedID'):string.

My questions are:

- Is it a good idea? (XML parsing --> JSON --> insert and indexing!)
- Can I use GridFS and get chunks equivalents to records for each file? How?
- Do you know other way?

Comment: Does it work?  Then it's good.  Are you having a problem?  If so, please provide the actual problem you're having.  It sounds like your real question is very simple -- how to use GridFS.  Perhaps you should focus specifically on what specific help you need.  "Do you know another way" is a silly question, there are an infinite number of other ways, most of which are a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you S.Lott! Yes, my exatc question would be, how can I combine GridFS with Medline Files?

àlex.

Comment: I have problems with my XML2JSON parser, because this XML is not trivial, and I do not know if GridFS can help me...

Comment: Àlex: These sound like two separate questions, only a little related to this question.  Before asking those other questions, please **read** as much as you can on GridFS and ask as **specific** a question as you can on using GridFS with Medline files.  All software can be integrated; you need to do a lot of reading so you can provide us some guidance and direction on how you would like to proceed.  "problems with my XML2JSON parser" is meaningless and confusing.  What **exact** problem do you have?  Please be very, very **specific** and include the actual code that causes the actual problem.

Comment: `I want to process these records and get information such as title, abstract` - sounds like you need elasticsearch, and not mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea? (XML parsing --> JSON --> insert and indexing!)

Does it work? JSON tends to be smaller than XML, this is probably a good change.

> Can I use GridFS and get chunks equivalents to records for each file? How?

GridFS is generally for storing static files like images or video. MongoDB can support very large documents (*16MB == several novels*). The text for a medline article is probably going to be much smaller than this.

If you are just planning to store text, then you should not need any GridFS. If you want to store images, then GridFS is useful for doing this.

Please read up on [GridFS here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS). Note that GridFS is just a specification. Everything is still stored inside of regular MongoDB collections.

---

PS: it looks like `pubmedID` is a unique key. You can save space by overriding the `_id` with `pubmedID` when you create the document.

*i.e.:* `collection.insert({"_id": xml_obj.pubmedID, "text" : xml_obj.article_text})`